# Memory segmentation in 8086 microprocessor

Tags: memory, x86

I have just started reading a book about 8086 microprocessor assembly and the inner parts of a computer. In the chapter about memory, I read that in order to bridge the gap between the 20 bit address bus and the 16 bit registers, the memory is split into different segments. It is noted that a logical memory address is made out of 2 registers, one holds the base address of the segment and the other holds the offset. It also says that the size of each segment is 64KB (2^16 addresses).

The book then explains how to convert a logical address into a physical one. It says that to get to the base address of the segment I need to multiply the number of the segment by 16 e.g. segment 0x0002 starts at 0x00020 and segment 0x0003 starts at 0x00030.

As I understand it, that means each segment contains only 16 bytes? And not 64KB as mentioned before?

Comment: `As I understand it, that means each segment contains only 16 bytes? And not 64KB as mentioned before?` No. They overlap.

Comment: I suspected that is the case. In that case, then that means that logical address 0x0002:0010 and 0x0003:0000 point to the same physical address?

Comment: `2*16 + 16` == `3*16 + 0`. Yes.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you very much!